# Finding element and index of an element in a vector in R

Tags: r

How can I find the first element and index of the element of a vector which is smaller than its previous element and it is smaller than its next element in R?

for example, we have a vector like this:

```
     x=c(100.5, 99, 98.5,95.2,110, 116, 120,130)
```

I would like to find 95.2 and index of this element in R.

Comment: @thelatemail sorry I just missed some part of the question

Comment: check the `diff` starting from the left and right are negative `x[c(FALSE, diff(x) < 0) & rev(c(FALSE, diff(rev(x)) < 0))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works, but I'm happy to be proven wrong:

```
x <- c(100.5, 99, 98.5, 95.2, 110, 116, 120, 130)
idx <- which(diff(sign(diff(x)))==2)+1
idx
#[1] 4
x[idx]
#[1] 95.2
```

It also doesn't consider the first value to be a possible result (not sure if this is what you want or not):

```
x <- 1:5
idx <- which(diff(sign(diff(x)))==2)+1
idx
#numeric(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
i1 <- which(c(x[-1] > x[-length(x)] & x[-length(x)] < x[-1]), FALSE)[1]
x[i1]
#[1] 95.2
```